# It's been more than 1 +1/2 month my app is not serving ads, with error I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

Tags: android, admob, firebase-admob

On 24th August, my AdMob account was set on "Ad serving limited and it says that this impact for less than 30 days but now its more than one and half month but things haven't changed.

Can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: I had the same problem as you. They unblocked my ads after 30 days

Comment: But for me, it's been more than a month but still, they are not releasing my account

Comment: @FrancescoBocci I hope so, I've been limited since Sept 14 and its draining my revenue. I don't know how much longer I can sustain the losses

Comment: @Tanishbansal did Admob remove the ad serving limit on your account? if yes, how many days or months it took to do it? It has been 2 months and they haven't removed the limit on my account.

Comment: @jaychandra that limit was lifted after about 2 months and now ad service was running completely fine for a month but again the limit has been placed. don't know why  Its not like that I don't have traffic, I do have about 300-350 regular users including international users still don't know what they want from us. Now me and my team is planning to switch to some other ad service.

Comment: @Tanishbansal How long it took to remove ad serving limit?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if your account is new or you don't have enough traffic. Keep building organic traffic to your app and ad servings will be resumed automatically.

Comment: It has been more than 40 days my ad serving limit is not removed. Inspite of having very very good traffic. What to do, please help.

Comment: Do you have organic traffic?
is you app published on google play?

Answer (score 0):

You tried removing the ad unit, when the limit on the account is removed wait 30 days and create a new unit. Currently your Admob account is limited or not